# PHP error : exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Illegal string offset 'id''

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am working with a an array and I get getting this error above, I working with a very simply array that looks like this,

```
    array (
       'Emails' =>
           array (
               0 =>
                   array (
                       'id' => 172,
                       'email' => 'sam@andrews.com',
                       'first_name' => 'Sam',
                       'last_name' => 'Andrews',
                       'display_name' => 'simonainley',
                       'initials' => 'SA',
                       'active' => 1,
                       'login_type' => 'normal',
                       'cost_visible' => 0,
                       'notification_frequency' => 'D',
                       'admin' => 1,
                       'pivot' =>
                       array (
                           'organisation_id' => 200,
                           'user_id' => 172,
                           'is_admin' => 1,
                       ),
                  ),
              1 =>
                  array (
                      'id' => 110,
                      'email' => 'mike@fish.com',
                      'first_name' => 'Mike',
                      'last_name' => 'Fish',
                      'display_name' => 'mikefish',
                      'initials' => 'MF',
                      'active' => 1,
                      'login_type' => 'normal',
                      'cost_visible' => 0,
                      'notification_frequency' => 'H',
                      'admin' => 1,
                      'pivot' =>
                      array (
                          'organisation_id' => 200,
                          'user_id' => 110,
                          'is_admin' => 1,
                      ),
                  ),
                  'notification' => 'A user changed the status of New SEA LTD Projectto <strong>completed</strong>.',
       ),
  )
```

This array gets set into a variable, and then I loop through it, like this,

```
foreach($data['emails'] as $email) {
        Log::info($email);
        $emailData['id'] = $email['id'];    
        $emailData['first_name'] = $email['first_name'];
        $emailData['last_name'] = $email['last_name'];
        $emailData['email'] = $email['email'];

        Log::info($emailData);
}
```

The `Log::info($email)` outputs the following,

```
array (
  'id' => 110,
  'email' => 'mike@fish.com',
  'first_name' => 'Mike',
  'last_name' => 'Fish',
  'display_name' => 'mikefish',
  'initials' => 'MF',
  'active' => 1,
  'login_type' => 'normal',
  'cost_visible' => 0,
  'notification_frequency' => 'H',
  'admin' => 1,
  'pivot' =>
  array (
    'organisation_id' => 200,
    'user_id' => 110,
    'is_admin' => 1,
  ),
)
```

The `Log::info($emailData)` outputs the following,

```
array (
    'id' => 110,
    'first_name' => 'Mike',
    'last_name' => 'Fish',
    'email' => 'mike@fish.com',
)
```

So I can see the 'id' attribute in my logs so why would i be seeing,

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Illegal string offset 'id''

the exception is being triggered by this line apparently,

`$emailData['id'] = $email['id'];`

any ideas?

Comment: By what line of code is the exception triggered?

Comment: @bogdan added an edit.

Comment: You have a third entry in your array `'notification' => 'A user changed...'` which does not have a an `id`.

Comment: @KirkBeard is right. You should place a condition in your `foreach` that checks if the array item is an array like so: `if (is_array($email))`, because the `notification` item is only a string and will not pass the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a third entry in your array `'notification' => 'A user changed...'` which is a string, and therefore does not have an `id` (nor does it have any of the other fields: `email`, `first_name`, etc).